# Hartl's ROR Chapter10 microposts test failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From chapter10.23, file: spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do
.
.
.
describe "authorization" do

describe "for non-signed-in users" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  .
  .
  .
  describe "in the Microposts controller" do

    describe "submitting to the create action" do
      before { post microposts_path }
      specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
    end

    describe "submitting to the destroy action" do
      before { delete micropost_path(FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)) }
      specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
end
end
```

when i tried to pass the test. one of them failed and the message is shown below:

```
1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Microposts controller 
 submitting to the destroy action
 Failure/Error: before { delete micropost_path(FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)) }
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: User can't be blank
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:90:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

the problem is I discontinued from learning ROR for a while so I don't know where I did wrong and why the test failed with this message.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)` is invalid! It looks like you have a vlidation of `user` on presense in `Micropost` but you did not specify `user` in factory.

You should define factory for micropost as

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :micropost do
    ...
    user
    ...
  end
end
```

or call `Factory.create` with existed user (you define user before in a let-block): `FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user)`

You should choose a way according to your needs (workflow logic)

Comment: thanks alot, i checked factories.rb and find some differences between my file and the file shown on book. thank you again! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was trying to do my own custom content and forgot to add the word 'user' to the factory.